# How to download USDZ as a Data object and convert it back as USDZ?

Tags: swift, usdz

I have uploaded my USDZ File as a Data object to the cloud. Now my question is how can I convert the Data object back to USDZ File if I download the data ?

Comment: Saving the data to disk and loading through a URL might work. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hey @EmilioPelaez thanks for your help. I tried to save the file to disk and load the Entity.load(contentsOf: fileURL). and seems it works. Thanks best regards

Comment: Hi @developerAvatar. Did you get it to work? I cant load it as Data.

Comment: Same here can't load it via Entity.load(contentsOf:)